# internal error occurred while Updating Maven Project getMavenProject

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse, when I right click on my project and click "Update Maven Project", I get the below error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
'org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.ProjectConfigurationRequest.getMavenProject()'
```

I know this looks like quite a few other StackOverflow posts, but none of those helped me, and very few reference this precise problem.  The closest I ever saw were ones referencing `getProject` instead of `getMavenProject`.  Most say to do things I already tried (see below).

I have tried pretty much everything:

- Ran `mvn eclipse:clean` and then `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
- Removed projected and re-imported it as a maven project
- Reloaded the entire workspace, after removing a bunch of plugins
- Removed .m2 directory and let it be rebuilt
- Probably something else I am forgetting
  The closest I ever got was when I removed some add-ons (m2e-wtp related stuff, if memory serves), but then a normal eclipse update added them back (when I started Eclipse next time, it popped up a message saying I needed to install them, so I clicked "Yes", hoping things were fixed).  I did try to uninstall these m2e-wtp, but that did not fix things, so I added them back (since it kept asking me to).

I expect to update the maven project with no error.  Basically, I want to get rid of the `getMavenProject` error, either by fixing something in my setup, or getting a fix from the m2e people (maybe the update site is not one of the ones I am using, for instance).

More information below:
Version information:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

Windows 11 Pro
Fully updated eclipse (just did "Check Updates").

Available Software sites export:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmarks>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06" selected="true" name="2022-06"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06/202206151000" selected="true" name="2022-06"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12" selected="true" name="2022-12"/>
   <site url="http://sdbg.github.io/p2" selected="true" name="com.github.sdbg.releng.p2"/>
   <site url="http://vaadin.com/eclipse/" selected="true" name="com.vaadin.update.site"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03" selected="true" name="Eclipse Repository"/>
   <site url="http://marketplace.yatta.de/eclipse-mirror/releases/2020-03" selected="true" name="Eclipse Repository"/>
   <site url="http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite" selected="true" name="IvyDE"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/latest/" selected="true" name="Latest Eclipse IDE Packages Release"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest" selected="true" name="Latest Eclipse Simultaneous Release"/>
   <site url="http://www.liclipse.com/text/updates" selected="true" name="LiClipseText Update Site"/>
   <site url="http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release" selected="true" name="repo"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/" selected="true" name="repository"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/lsp4e/releases/0.20.7/" selected="true" name="repository"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/1.0.0/" selected="true" name="repository"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.25/" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project repository"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.24" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project Updates"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.26" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project Updates"/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/latest" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/usssdk/updates/release/latest" selected="true" name="User Storage Latest Release"/>
   <site url="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/updatesite" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2022-06/202206091200" selected="true" name=""/>
</bookmarks>
```

Error log for above error message:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=19.0.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.jobs
Error
Fri Feb 10 16:55:52 EST 2023
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.ProjectConfigurationRequest.getMavenProject()'
    at com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.maven.VaadinMavenProjectConfigurator.getSourceFolders(VaadinMavenProjectConfigurator.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.AbstractSourcesGenerationProjectConfigurator.configureRawClasspath(AbstractSourcesGenerationProjectConfigurator.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.invokeJavaProjectConfigurators(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$6(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$4(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$3(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Doing `mvn eclipse:...` is wrong nowadays. Anything in the _Error Log_ view? If yes, please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: The problem indicated by stacktrace is that the plugin tries to use method from maven integration that is not there. This indicates that there is a dependency compatibility issue. I recall that such error should have been fixed in the newest version of Vaadin Eclipse Plugin, can you verify you use the latest version?

Comment: Plugin version 4.1.7, if I am reading it correctly.  I just tried to update it and it said that no updates were found.  Update sites are http://vaadin.com/eclipse/ and https://vaadin.com/eclipse/.  Eclipse version is 2023-03 (4.27.0), build 20230309-1520.  The vaadin version I am using is 7.7.17 (the latest I can currently use because of my licensing and the type of account I have).